# Pass a collection of Items from the view to the controller. MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to edit a model that contains a collection of another model as member. I'd like to create a table simulating a grid for editing this collection of items. Then, when submitting the form I want to pass the following parameters to the controller.

```
public ActionResult SavePerformanceGraphItem(int itemId, ICollection<PerformanceGraphItem> items)
{

}
```

How should I name the inputs in the view in order to be retrieved by the controller as I'd like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the names of the input fields would be something like:

```
name="items[0].PropertyOne"
name="items[0].PropertyTwo"
...
name="items[1].PropertyOne"
name="items[1].PropertyTwo"
...
name="items[2].PropertyOne"
name="items[2].PropertyTwo"
```

etc.

Comment: Awesome!!! I spend hours on web and got lots of solutions that did not work. This worked like a charm. You made my day!

Comment: kind of crazy that still happens for such old answers :)  Thanks for sharing, I love SO